# popover shows “[object Object]” on ajax

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-ajax, popover, bootstrap-popover

[image]

As u see the picture , My bootstrap popover triggers and shows “[object Object]” instead of the data I retrieved from database. I put logs on js ajax code and seen that I retrieve data however cant show it up on popover. What can be the problem ?

```
          <script >
    
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tog').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            console.log("Popover initialization started.");
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                placement: 'right',
                title: 'Update Changes',
                trigger: 'hover',
                html: true,
    
                content: function () {
                    console.log("Popover content loading started.");
                    var reasonCode = $(this).closest('tr').find('.reason_code').text();
                    console.log("Reason code:", reasonCode);
                    return $.ajax({
    
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'CCA_Crups_Reason.aspx/GetPopoverContent',
                        data: JSON.stringify({ reasonCode: reasonCode }),
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (response) {
                            //Extract the data from the response
                            var data = response.d;
    
                            console.log(data)
    
                            return data
    
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            console.error(xhr.responseText);
                            console.error("Ajax request failed:", xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    
            
      });
    
    
        
    
    </script>

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you're trying to display is not a string. `[object Object]` is Javascript's default conversion from an object to a string.

You can double-check the datatype of the function response data by updating your log to `console.log(typeof data)`, which will help you to format the data appropriately.